# NoClassDefFoundError: java.io.FileOutputStream is a restricted class

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload, apache-commons

I'm developing a google app in java, but I'm getting this error: `java.io.FileOutputStream is a restricted class` only
when i try to upload a csv file bigger than others.
All works fine when I upload file like 5-6kb, I get errors with 30kb file.
I imported all libs of course and read some tutorial/questions but I do not know to solve this problem.

code on servlet:

```
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        upload.setFileSizeMax(50000);
        upload.setSizeMax(50000);
        List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(req); // <-- error line (48)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.io.FileOutputStream is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:50)
at org.apache.commons.io.output.DeferredFileOutputStream.thresholdReached(DeferredFileOutputStream.java:178)
at org.apache.commons.io.output.ThresholdingOutputStream.checkThreshold(ThresholdingOutputStream.java:224)
at org.apache.commons.io.output.ThresholdingOutputStream.write(ThresholdingOutputStream.java:128)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:108)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:70)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:347)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
at it.injenia.gestionefirme.servlet.uploadkind.UploadKind.doPost(UploadKind.java:48)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Google App Engine application is not allowed to write to the file system.

Uploading works for smaller files, because they're kept in memory. To store larger files in memory, you can increase the default size threshold of 10KB.

Documentation: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItemFactory.html

Comment: This is actually no longer true, writing to `/tmp` is now allowed: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/migrating-to-java8#taking_full_advantage_of_java_8_runtime_features